# Spark Window Functions: Filter out rows with start and end dates within the bounds of another rows start and end dates

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, window-functions

I have a DataFrame (sqlDF) similar to the following (simplified for this example) in which I'm trying to remove any rows that have a start_date and end_date within the bounds of another row's start and end dates:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    id |         type|         start_date|           end_date|
+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1    |      unknown|2018-11-14 16:03:47|2018-12-06 21:23:22| (remove as it's within the next rows start and end dates)
|  1    |          ios|2018-10-13 14:58:22|2019-08-26 15:50:45|
|  1    |      android|2019-08-29 02:41:40|2019-09-05 23:03:20|
|  2    |          ios|2017-12-19 02:25:34|2019-08-09 15:41:30|
|  2    |      windows|2018-07-10 05:30:52|2018-07-13 10:11:34| (remove as it's within the previous row's start and end dates)
|  2    |      android|2019-05-14 18:33:15|2019-08-27 06:10:53| (remove as it's within another row's start and end dates)
```

First, the end user then asked me to remove any records with a start_date and end_date of less than 5 days between, which I did with the following:

```
val dfWithoutTempHandsets = sqlDF.filter(datediff(col("end_date"), col("start_date")) > 5)
```

resulting in a DataFrame like so:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    id |         type|         start_date|           end_date|
+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1    |      unknown|2018-11-14 16:03:47|2018-12-06 21:23:22| 
|  1    |          ios|2018-10-13 14:58:22|2019-08-26 15:50:45|
|  1    |      android|2019-08-29 02:41:40|2019-09-05 23:03:20|
|  2    |          ios|2017-12-19 02:25:34|2019-08-09 15:41:30|
|  2    |      android|2019-05-14 18:33:15|2019-06-27 06:10:53|
```

Now I need to filter out rows where the start and end dates are 'within' another row's start and end dates for that same id, such that the resultant DataFrame would look like:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    id |         type|         start_date|           end_date|
+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1    |          ios|2018-10-13 14:58:22|2019-08-26 15:50:45|
|  1    |      android|2019-08-29 02:41:40|2019-09-05 23:03:20|
|  2    |          ios|2017-12-19 02:25:34|2019-08-09 15:41:30|
```

After reading several blog posts and stack overflow posts on spark window functions, I know that that is the answer. But I'm struggling to find examples for a similar use case where multiple dates are compared to another rows' dates in this fashion. I believe I have a windowSpec that is close:

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id", "type").orderBy("start_date")
```

But from there I'm not sure how to utilize the windowSpec to select only rows that don't have start and end dates within those of another rows for that id.

Edit: I was given a new requirement to only apply the above logic for rows with a "NULL" or "Unknown" types. But the answers here were getting me closer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the logic I would consider using:

> Under a Window partition by `id` with `start_date` in ascending order, if the `end_date` in the current row is older than or equal to the `end_date` in ANY of the previous rows, the date range in the current row must be contained within some date range(s) in the previous row(s).

Translating that into sample code (including also the `> 5 days` filtering):

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "unknown", Timestamp.valueOf("2018-11-14 16:03:47"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-12-06 21:23:22")),
  (1, "ios", Timestamp.valueOf("2018-10-13 14:58:22"), Timestamp.valueOf("2019-08-26 15:50:45")),
  (1, "android", Timestamp.valueOf("2019-08-29 02:41:40"), Timestamp.valueOf("2019-09-05 23:03:20")),
  (2, "ios", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-12-19 02:25:34"), Timestamp.valueOf("2019-08-09 15:41:30")),
  (2, "unknown", Timestamp.valueOf("2018-07-10 05:30:52"), Timestamp.valueOf("2018-07-13 10:11:34")),
  (2, "android", Timestamp.valueOf("2019-05-14 18:33:15"), Timestamp.valueOf("2019-06-27 06:10:53"))
).toDF("id", "type", "start_date", "end_date")

val win = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy($"start_date").
  rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

df.
  where(unix_timestamp($"end_date") - unix_timestamp($"start_date") > 5*24*3600).
  withColumn("isContained",
    when($"end_date" <= max($"end_date").over(win), true).otherwise(false)
  ).
  where(! $"isContained").
  show
// +---+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+
// | id|   type|         start_date|           end_date|isContained|
// +---+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+
// |  1|    ios|2018-10-13 14:58:22|2019-08-26 15:50:45|      false|
// |  1|android|2019-08-29 02:41:40|2019-09-05 23:03:20|      false|
// |  2|    ios|2017-12-19 02:25:34|2019-08-09 15:41:30|      false|
// +---+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Note that for the `> 5 days` filtering, I'm using `unix_timestamp` instead of `datediff`, which only mechanically compares the difference in the `day` values (e.g. datediff(`2019-01-06 12:00:00`, `2019-01-01 00:00:00`) > `5` is false).

Comment: This is great! Say I needed to only apply this logic for rows where the type is "Null" or "unknown", would I simply add a second "when" outside of your when? (see latest edit)

Comment: @alaskanloops, from what you've described it sounds more likely the additional condition should be within the existing `when` clause, like, `when(($"type" === "unknown" || $"type".isNull) && $"end_date" <= max ...)`.  Keep in mind, though, the window spec `win` applies to all previous rows for every current row within the same `id` regardless of `type`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val sqlDF = Seq((1,"unknown","2018-11-14 16:03:47","2018-12-06 21:23:22"),(1,"ios","2018-10-13 14:58:22","2019-08-26 15:50:45"),(1,"android","2019-08-29 02:41:40","2019-09-05 23:03:20"),(2,"ios","2017-12-19 02:25:34","2019-08-09 15:41:30"),(2,"unknown","2018-07-10 05:30:52","2018-07-13 10:11:34"),(2,"android","2019-05-14 18:33:15","2019-06-27 06:10:53")).toDF("id","type","start_date","end_date")

val dfWithoutTempHandsets = sqlDF.filter(datediff(col("end_date"), col("start_date")) > 5)

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(dfWithoutTempHandsets("id")).orderBy(dfWithoutTempHandsets("start_date"))

val windowSpec1 = Window.partitionBy(dfWithoutTempHandsets("id")).orderBy((dfWithoutTempHandsets("end_date").desc))

val dense = first(dfWithoutTempHandsets("start_date")).over(windowSpec)

val dense1 = first(dfWithoutTempHandsets("end_date")).over(windowSpec1)

val temp = dfWithoutTempHandsets.select(dfWithoutTempHandsets("id"),dfWithoutTempHandsets("type"),dfWithoutTempHandsets("start_date"),dfWithoutTempHandsets("end_date"),dense.alias("min_start_date"),dense1.alias("max_end_date"))

val finalDf = temp.filter(temp("start_date").leq(temp("min_start_date")).or(temp("end_date").geq(temp("max_end_date"))))

finalDf.show(false)
```